# check on certain page if any user is logged in or not in jsp

Tags: java

i have a main page in which, if the user is logged in, then only he could visit the next page.If not, he would be directed to login page and after user login, he would be directed right where he left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario you can use [spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) ([tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/)) which basically check that you have access to this page or not if not then first login page display after successfully login it can redirect to next page.
spring also provide default login page. 
You can also do it manually that using preserving login state of user.

For manually checking login status:

Suppose you have 4 pages

1)login page:

check users credentials and after login store session id to user database 
and return it to user for next request

2)page 2

fetche previous session id and check it with user session id, if matched then show next page else show login page

3)page 3

4)page 4

code for accessing session

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
int sessionId = (int) session.getAttribute("sessionId");
```

Comment: i want to do it with just coding only without using any framework. Isnt there any way to do it with just jsp or servlet code

Comment: Yes, you can use simple jsp servlate redirection to check login status.In every request check user login status(store it into database and use session) and simply redirect login page or next page with respect to login status